# Texture mapping with phong lighting

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, phong

Im trying to add Phong lighting to my scene in which I have loaded mesh with textures. This is my mesh loadin class:

```
#define INVALID_OGL_VALUE 0xFFFFFFFF
#define INVALID_MATERIAL 0xFFFFFFFF
#define SAFE_DELETE(p) if (p) { delete p; p = NULL; }

Mesh::MeshEntry::MeshEntry()
{
    VB = INVALID_OGL_VALUE;
    IB = INVALID_OGL_VALUE;
    NumIndices  = 0;
    MaterialIndex = INVALID_MATERIAL;
};

Mesh::MeshEntry::~MeshEntry()
{
    if (VB != INVALID_OGL_VALUE)
    {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VB);
    }

    if (IB != INVALID_OGL_VALUE)
    {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &IB);
    }
}

void Mesh::MeshEntry::Init(const std::vector<Vertex>& Vertices,
                          const std::vector<unsigned int>& Indices)
{
    NumIndices = Indices.size();

    glGenBuffers(1, &VB);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VB);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex) * Vertices.size(), &Vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &IB);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IB);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * NumIndices, &Indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

Mesh::Mesh()
{
}


Mesh::~Mesh()
{
    Clear();
}


void Mesh::Clear()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < textures_cnt.size() ; i++) {
        SAFE_DELETE(textures_cnt[i]);
    }
}


/*Loads mesh
 *@Filename -   name of the .obj file
 **********************************************************/
bool Mesh::LoadMesh(const std::string& Filename){

    Assimp::Importer Importer;
    bool rc = false;

    //clear previous loaded mesh
    Clear();

    //read file content
    const aiScene* oScene = Importer.ReadFile(Filename.c_str(), aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_GenSmoothNormals | aiProcess_FlipUVs );

    if(oScene){

        printf ("  %i animations\n", oScene->mNumAnimations);
        printf ("  %i cameras\n", oScene->mNumCameras);
        printf ("  %i lights\n", oScene->mNumLights);
        printf ("  %i materials\n", oScene->mNumMaterials);
        printf ("  %i meshes\n", oScene->mNumMeshes);
        printf ("  %i textures\n", oScene->mNumTextures);

        submeshes_cnt.resize(oScene->mNumMeshes);
        textures_cnt.resize(oScene->mNumMaterials);

        /*.........Initialize the meshes in the scene one by one...........*/
        for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < submeshes_cnt.size() ; i++) {

            const aiMesh* paiMesh = oScene->mMeshes[i];
            InitMesh(i, paiMesh);
        }

        // Extract the directory part from the file name
        std::string::size_type SlashIndex = Filename.find_last_of("/");
        std::string Dir;

        if (SlashIndex == std::string::npos) {
            Dir = ".";
        }
        else if (SlashIndex == 0) {
            Dir = "/";
        }
        else {
            Dir = Filename.substr(0, SlashIndex);
        }
        /*.................Initialization of meshes end....................*/



        /*.............Initialize the materials.............................*/
        for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < oScene->mNumMaterials ; i++) {
            const aiMaterial* pMaterial = oScene->mMaterials[i];

            textures_cnt[i] = NULL;

            if (pMaterial->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE) > 0) {
                aiString Path;

                if (pMaterial->GetTexture(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, 0, &Path, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == AI_SUCCESS) {
                    std::string FullPath = Dir + "/" + Path.data;
                    textures_cnt[i] = new Texture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FullPath.c_str());

                    if (!textures_cnt[i]->Load()) {
                        printf("Error loading texture '%s'\n", FullPath.c_str());
                        delete textures_cnt[i];
                        textures_cnt[i] = NULL;
                        rc = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("Loaded texture '%s'\n", FullPath.c_str());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /*.................Initialization of materials end....................*/
    }
    else {
        printf("Error parsing '%s': '%s'\n", Filename.c_str(), Importer.GetErrorString());
    }

    return rc;
}


void Mesh::InitMesh(unsigned int Index, const aiMesh* paiMesh)
{
    submeshes_cnt[Index].MaterialIndex = paiMesh->mMaterialIndex;

    std::vector<Vertex> Vertices;
    std::vector<unsigned int> Indices;

    const aiVector3D Zero3D(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < paiMesh->mNumVertices ; i++) {
        const aiVector3D* pPos      = &(paiMesh->mVertices[i]);
        const aiVector3D* pNormal   = &(paiMesh->mNormals[i]);
        const aiVector3D* pTexCoord = paiMesh->HasTextureCoords(0) ? &(paiMesh->mTextureCoords[0][i]) : &Zero3D;

        Vertex v(Vector3f(pPos->x, pPos->y, pPos->z),
                 Vector2f(pTexCoord->x, pTexCoord->y),
                 Vector3f(pNormal->x, pNormal->y, pNormal->z));

        Vertices.push_back(v);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < paiMesh->mNumFaces ; i++) {
        const aiFace& Face = paiMesh->mFaces[i];
        assert(Face.mNumIndices == 3);
        Indices.push_back(Face.mIndices[0]);
        Indices.push_back(Face.mIndices[1]);
        Indices.push_back(Face.mIndices[2]);
    }

    submeshes_cnt[Index].Init(Vertices, Indices);
}

void Mesh::Render(){

    //enable VAOs for vertices, normals, textures
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < submeshes_cnt.size() ; i++){

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, submeshes_cnt[i].VB);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid*)12);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid*)20);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, submeshes_cnt[i].IB);

        const unsigned int MaterialIndex = submeshes_cnt[i].MaterialIndex;

        if (MaterialIndex < textures_cnt.size() && textures_cnt[MaterialIndex]) {
            textures_cnt[MaterialIndex]->Bind(GL_TEXTURE0);
        }

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, submeshes_cnt[i].NumIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);


}
```

vertex shader:

```
#version 420

uniform mat4 camera;
uniform mat4 model;

in vec3 vert;
in vec2 vertTexCoord;

out vec2 fragTexCoord;

void main() {
    // Pass the tex coord straight through to the fragment shader
    fragTexCoord = vertTexCoord;

    // Apply all matrix transformations to vert
    gl_Position = camera * model * vec4(vert, 1);
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 420

uniform sampler2D tex;

in vec2 fragTexCoord;

out vec4 finalColor;

void main() {
    //note: the texture function was called texture2D in older versions of GLSL
    finalColor = texture(tex, fragTexCoord);
}
```

this is what i get:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mT0c.jpg)

but when i try to add phong lighting, when I add in attribute for normals to my vertex shader this is what I get:
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQGFx.jpg)

Where is the problem?
Thank you for help.

//edit
shader loading and link

```
shprogram::shprogram(const std::vector<shader>& shaders) :
    _object(0)
{
    if(shaders.size() <= 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("No shaders were provided to create the program");

    //create the program object
    _object = glCreateProgram();
    if(_object == 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("glCreateProgram failed");

    //attach all the shaders
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < shaders.size(); ++i)
        glAttachShader(_object, shaders[i].getObject());

    //link the shaders together
    glLinkProgram(_object);

    //detach all the shaders
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < shaders.size(); ++i)
        glDetachShader(_object, shaders[i].getObject());

    //throw exception if linking failed
    GLint status;
    glGetProgramiv(_object, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == GL_FALSE) {
        std::string msg("Program linking failure: ");

        GLint infoLogLength;
        glGetProgramiv(_object, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
        char* strInfoLog = new char[infoLogLength + 1];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(_object, infoLogLength, NULL, strInfoLog);
        msg += strInfoLog;
        delete[] strInfoLog;

        glDeleteProgram(_object); _object = 0;
        throw std::runtime_error(msg);
    }
}

shprogram::~shprogram() {
    //might be 0 if ctor fails by throwing exception
    if(_object != 0) glDeleteProgram(_object);
}

GLuint shprogram::object() const {
    return _object;
}

void shprogram::use() const {
    glUseProgram(_object);
}

bool shprogram::isInUse() const {
    GLint currentProgram = 0;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM, &currentProgram);
    return (currentProgram == (GLint)_object);
}

void shprogram::stopUsing() const {
    assert(isInUse());
    glUseProgram(0);
}

GLint shprogram::attrib(const GLchar* attribName) const {
    if(!attribName)
        throw std::runtime_error("attribName was NULL");

    GLint attrib = glGetAttribLocation(_object, attribName);
    if(attrib == -1)
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Program attribute not found: ") + attribName);

    return attrib;
}

GLint shprogram::uniform(const GLchar* uniformName) const {
    if(!uniformName)
        throw std::runtime_error("uniformName was NULL");

    GLint uniform = glGetUniformLocation(_object, uniformName);
    if(uniform == -1)
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Program uniform not found: ") + uniformName);

    return uniform;
}

void shprogram::setUniformMatrix2(const GLchar* name, const GLfloat* v, GLsizei count, GLboolean transpose) {
    assert(isInUse());
    glUniformMatrix2fv(uniform(name), count, transpose, v);
}

void shprogram::setUniformMatrix3(const GLchar* name, const GLfloat* v, GLsizei count, GLboolean transpose) {
    assert(isInUse());
    glUniformMatrix3fv(uniform(name), count, transpose, v);
}

void shprogram::setUniformMatrix4(const GLchar* name, const GLfloat* v, GLsizei count, GLboolean transpose) {
    assert(isInUse());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform(name), count, transpose, v);
}

void shprogram::setUniform(const GLchar* name, const glm::mat2& m, GLboolean transpose) {
    assert(isInUse());
    glUniformMatrix2fv(uniform(name), 1, transpose, glm::value_ptr(m));
}

void shprogram::setUniform(const GLchar* name, const glm::mat3& m, GLboolean transpose) {
    assert(isInUse());
    glUniformMatrix3fv(uniform(name), 1, transpose, glm::value_ptr(m));
}

void shprogram::setUniform(const GLchar* name, const glm::mat4& m, GLboolean transpose) {
    assert(isInUse());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform(name), 1, transpose, glm::value_ptr(m));
}

void shprogram::setUniform(const GLchar* uniformName, const glm::vec3& v) {
    setUniform3v(uniformName, glm::value_ptr(v));
}

void shprogram::setUniform(const GLchar* uniformName, const glm::vec4& v) {
    setUniform4v(uniformName, glm::value_ptr(v));
}
```

setting up uniforms

```
//bind shader program
gProgram->use();

//set the "camera" uniform
gProgram->setUniform("camera", gCamera.matrix());

//set the "model" uniform in the vertex shader, based on the gDegreesRotated global
gProgram->setUniform("model", glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), 150.0f ,glm::vec3(0,1,0)));


gProgram->setUniform("light.position", gLight.position);
gProgram->setUniform("light.intensities", gLight.intensities);
```

Comment: Pleaso provide your shader compilation and linking code. My guess so far would be that you did not specify the attribute locations.

Comment: You have code in your question that can be used to query vertex attribute locations (`GLint shprogram::attrib(const GLchar* attribName) const`), but you are not using it! *tsk-tsk.* Also, ***consider re-naming this function***, because there are multiple operations that can be performed on vertex attribute locations - you can query them after linking, you can bind them before linking, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neither explicitely set the attribute locations in the shader source, nor bind them before linking the shader, nor query them. The GL is free to use any valid attribute index for any active input attribute.

You just *assume* that 0 is position, 1 is texcoord and 2 is normal. It might work by accident for the position+texcoord case, but when you add the normal, the indices might get all mixed up. Either use `layout(location=...)` (see [`GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/explicit_attrib_location.txt) for details) in the GLSL code, or use [`glBindAttribLocation()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindAttribLocation.xml) to specify the mapping you want.

Comment: Good catch. There is one exception to this rule, *though it does not apply here*... `glVertexPointer (...)` (the function used to set the vertex position pointer in fixed-function OpenGL) is the only pointer function that aliases (or at least, is allowed to in a compliant implementation) to an attribute slot in GLSL -- it aliases to `0`. I think this behavior is responsible for a lot of the assumptions that the attribute slots will always work in a sequential fashion, or that binding attribute locations is unnecessary; sadly, I think it does more harm than good to define this behavior :-\

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Hehe, it is worse than that. In compatibility mode, attribute 0 is kind of special as it completely mirros all of the old vertex specification functionality - calling `glVertexAttrib(0,...)` inside `glBegin()/End()` does actually emit the vertex... Weird stuff.